# Deleting Sprites in Pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I have a tile map that runs through a for loop similar to this:

```
def Draw_Level( x, y, column, obsticles, entities, image_cache ):

    #Grass#
    if column == "G":
        g = Grass(x, y, image_cache)
        entities.add(g)
    #Plain Grass#
    elif column == "P":
        p = Plain_Grass(x,y, image_cache)
        entities.add(p)
    #Grass with yellow flower#
    elif column == "F":
        f = Grass_Flower(x,y, image_cache)
        entities.add(f)
    #Grass To Sand (50/50 split block) Direct#
    elif column == "Y":
        q = Grass_To_SandD(x,y, image_cache)
        entities.add(q)

#Example If a class
class Grass(Entity):

    def __init__(self, x, y, image_cache):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = functions.get_image("data/images/Grass.png", image_cache)
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)
```

Say, for example, my mouse was clicked upon one of these and the x and y were determined to the nearest 32 (which is the width and height of the blocks). How would I determine what sprite is clicked? For example, if I clicked over a "grass" block, with the coordinates at which that grass block is drawn to the screen, how do I remove it?

Entites = a list holding all the entities

Is there a way I can call it from the entities list? It confuses me calling a Rect through a list, so that is why I am stuck :S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is called "hit-detection" or "[hit-testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit-testing)". In the case of your code it would entail going through the list of entities and checking the x,y location of the mouse-click against the extents of the rectangle each is occupying.

If you make each a class, you could add a method `hit_test(self, x, y)` to them and call it on each one. Something along these lines:

```
class Grass(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y, image_cache):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = functions.get_image("data/images/Grass.png", image_cache)
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)
    def hit_test(self, x, y):
        return (self.rect.x <= x < self.rect.x+self.rect.width and 
                self.rect.y <= y < self.rect.y+self.rect.height)
```

Comment: Thankyou, I managed to get it. Also, thanks for the infromation on hit testing.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that this could be sped-up by pre-computing the x and y boundaries and storing them in the Entity. Like-wise, you may be able to apply the same logic to whole groups of them that are stacked together by not checking any of them if the mouse x,y is outside of the (imaginary) bounding-box the encompasses all of them. This is called a "[trivial rejection](http://www.expertsmind.com/questions/trivial-rejection-case-of-cohen-sutherland-line-clippings-30149795.aspx)" and is used in line-clipping.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`rect.collidepoint`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) to determine if the mouse cursor is inside a rect.

```
entities_the_mouse_is_over = [entity for entity in entities if entity.rect.collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y)]
```

If you wish to use this approach, reconsider your rounding algorithm. This won't work when either of `mouse_x` or `mouse_y` are rounded up to the nearest 32. For example, suppose a tile has a rect of `(0,0,32,32)`, and the user clicks at (20,20). `mouse_x` and `mouse_y` will be rounded up to (32,32), which is not inside rect(0,0,32,32) as far as `collidepoint` is concerned.

If you only ever round *down*, then `collidepoint` will work. In the previous example, (20,20) would round down to (0,0), which is inside rect(0,0,32,32).

You could also just not do any rounding at all.